# inserting data in sqlce from asp.net form

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-ce

I am trying to insert names (string) in to a test database (sqlce). Basically, user will type in name in the textbox (input_box) and click on "Insert Button". Upon click of the button, a call is made to "submit" function. I want the text from the textbox to be used as the parameter for insertcommand. I don't get any error while running it. But when I check the data in the table, only "null" is inserted. I am trying to learn asp.net. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server"><title>Test run</title></head>
    <script language="C#" runat = "server">
        void Submit(object o, EventArgs e) 
        {
            SqlDataSource1.Insert();            
        }       
    </script>
<body style="height: 395px">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">   
    <asp:TextBox ID="Input_box" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
    <asp:Button ID="Insert_button" runat="server" Text=" Insert Button"  OnClick = "Submit"/>
        <asp:SqlDataSource 
            ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO Incident_Table(Assignee) VALUES (@assignee)" 
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT Assignee FROM Incident_Table">
            <InsertParameters>            
                <asp:FormParameter Name="assignee"  FormField ="name"/>
            </InsertParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GvK3S.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should replace this:

```
<asp:FormParameter Name="assignee"  FormField ="name"/>
```

with:

```
<asp:FormParameter Name="assignee" FormField="Input_box" />
```

Comment: Thank you Davide. That solved my problem :). I also have datetime parameter but I am not sure how to insert it as a parameter. Since it won't be user input, I don't think I should user FormParameter. Could you provide some ideas? Thank you for your answer.